# How to use inequalites in cmd code

Tags: math, command-line, batch-file, cmd, inequalities

I was making a code to find square roots for practice with basic cmd coding. However, when I type in a negative number, or an imperfect square, then it goes in an infinite loop. I know how to fix it, but I need to be able to use inequalities( Less than, greater than). (x is the number I have, and y is it's square root) That way I can say:

- if %x% (is less than) 0 (Don't operate)
- if %y% (is greater than) %x% (Don't operate)

or I could create another variable that is everything less(z)/greater(n) than x:

- if %x% == %z% (Don't operate)
- if %x% == %n% (Don't operate)

Please help me. I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try reading the documentation for the IF statement - type `HELP IF` or `IF /?` from the command line. About halfway through it describes the command extensions that support inequalities, such as LSS for less than.

```
if 0 lss 1 (echo 0 is less than 1) else (echo 0 is not less than 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @dbenham's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467452/63733), here's the excerpt of the `IF` documentation with all the **comparison operators**:

> If Command Extensions are enabled IF changes as follows:
>
> ```
> IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command
> IF CMDEXTVERSION number command
> IF DEFINED variable command
> ```
>
> where compare-op may be one of:
>
> ```
> EQU - equal
> NEQ - not equal
> LSS - less than
> LEQ - less than or equal
> GTR - greater than
> GEQ - greater than or equal
> ```

Comment: I intentionally didn't include the excerpt because I wanted to encourage the OP to use the HELP system :-)

Comment: That's why your answer is the better one ... :-) There's still a lot of information in the documentation one ought to read to really understand the possibilities. So if the OP is really in practice mode, she will explore the doc, and all other people stumbling onto this question just looking for a quick answer have the list available right here.

Answer (score 0):

Well in code this would look something like this

```
:: this is Regional settings dependant so tweak this according 
:: your current Windows regional settings
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=,: " %%a in ('echo %time%') do set hhmmsss=%%a%%b%%c

if /i %hhmmsss% LSS 95959 SET hhmmsss=0%hhmmsss%
```